# File input in Java for Mac

Tags: java, macos, file-io

We're learning file input and output in my programming class right now, but I have a Macbook Pro. I understand how to do it and I can do it on Windows but I'm having trouble finding out how to do it exactly for a Mac. I just can't seem to figure out what to put in the quotes for the 'File Fred = new File(" "); What do I need to put in the quotes to have it work? I have the file in the HDD named "David".

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class FileIO
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    File Fred = new File("David:\\mytext.txt");
    try
    {
```

Comment: *crosses fingers that you don't get an `ImSorryDaveICantLetYouDoThatException`*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Mac OS, you use "/" (forward slash) and not "\" (backward slash) to separate files in a path. Hard drives are located under "/Volumes". So your file is probably /Volumes/David/mytext.txt .

Comment: Thank you. That worked, but now it's giving me the output I want plus a bunch of other stuff. {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1038\cocoasubrtf350
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0
Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
\margl1440\margr1440\vieww9000\viewh8400\viewkind0
\pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\ql\qnatural\pardirnatural
\f0\fs24
\cf0
CIS
260
is
cool.\
Let's
put
another
sentence
in
here.\
Programming
is
problem
driven.}

Comment: Your file is in RTF (Rich Text Format). Edit it with TextEdit and use TextEdit preferences to default to plain text.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use "/" or "\" at all -- use System.getProperty("file.separator"). This will give you the correct character on the current OS. There are system properties that will help you write good cross-platform code. Check out System.getProperties() in the javadocs.

For example, to create "file.txt" in your home directory:

File myFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "file.txt");

That will work on OS X, Windows, and Linux.

Comment: / is universally supported across all major platforms nowadays

Answer (score 1):

`new File("/");` is your root in the MacOS filesystem.

Just open a Terminal, cd to / and things will be revealed to you.

Answer (score 1):

You won't use the same type of file path string you would on Windows. AFAIK your Mac should treat file paths the same as other *nix operating systems, with the "top" of the file system being `/` rather than `C:\`.

You can also address files as relative paths, rather than absolute paths. If you run your Java program from some directory `./program`, with your text file in `./program/file.txt`, then your argument is simply `new File("file.txt");`

Answer (score 0):

Try just dragging your file from  your desktop, to a terminal page. This will give you the exact path you need to type into you Java program. Also use text edit's `format` `Make Plain Text` to make sure it is in the correct form to be read by Java.