# Java scanner reading garbage

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am reading a text file using java Scanner.

```
try {
            while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
                //Read input from file
                inputLine = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
                System.out.println(inputLine);
}
```

The above gives below output while my text file only includes "aabbcc".
How to avoid scanner from scanning the garbage?
Thanks.

```
{\RTF1\ANSI\ANSICPG1252\COCOARTF1265\COCOASUBRTF210
{\FONTTBL\F0\FSWISS\FCHARSET0 HELVETICA;}
{\COLORTBL;\RED255\GREEN255\BLUE255;}
\PAPERW11900\PAPERH16840\MARGL1440\MARGR1440\VIEWW10800\VIEWH8400\VIEWKIND0
\PARD\TX566\TX1133\TX1700\TX2267\TX2834\TX3401\TX3968\TX4535\TX5102\TX5669\TX6236\TX6803\PARDIRNATURAL

\F0\FS24 \CF0 AABBCC}
```

Comment: Does your file really end with a .txt?

Comment: This does not look like you're reading a text file. What do you see when you display this in a naive text editor (or, on a posix machine, if you cat it to the terminal)?

Comment: You need to save your document as a plain text file not as an *.rtf file.

Comment: [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are reading a RTF Document. If you want to read the text only you can try reading it into a byte array and parsing out the text using swings rtfeditorkit.

```
Path path = Paths.get("path/to/file");
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);

RTFEditorKit rtfParser = new RTFEditorKit();
Document document = rtfParser.createDefaultDocument();
rtfParser.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(data), document, 0);
String text = document.getText(0, document.getLength());
```

Answer (score 3):

This was solved by setting TextEdit preferences, Format to "Plain text" and recreated the input file.
Managed to get the output without garbage.

Source: [File input in Java for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237663/file-input-in-java-for-mac)

Comment: If I could upvote this again I would. Just spent like 3 hours trying to figure out how to get this issue resolved

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't that the Scanner is reading in garbage. It is that your file isn't plain text. From the looks of it, your file is actually "rich text", and that garbage contains formatting info. I was able to produce similar output by saving a .rtf using MS WordPad.