# I am getting unexpected text

Tags: java

I have text.txt file that contains only three lines of text and this is my code to read the three line of text

```
package textFile;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class app {
public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String location = "/Users/li/Desktop/all files/text.rtf";
    File file = new File(location);
    Scanner text = new Scanner(file);
    while(text.hasNextLine()) {
        System.out.println(text.nextLine());
    }
    text.close();
}


}
```

I am getting this

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1561\cocoasubrtf400
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
{\*\expandedcolortbl;;}
\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
  \pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\ 
tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0

\f0\fs24 \cf0 Line 1 text\
Line 2 text\
Line 3 text}
```

Comment: Can you show us the content of text file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java scanner reading garbage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26565967/java-scanner-reading-garbage)

Comment: You are reading  a rft file not txt file are both same?

Comment: If that's all you get from reading a Rich Text Format (RTF) file of three text lines then consider yourself lucky. Open a new document in MS Word and enter **Hello World** then save the document as **.rtf**. Now view the file in Notepad. See if you can find **Hello World** in that mess without a search mechanism. Yup....Waldo it's about a third of the way down.

Comment: Please accept the answer which helped you most in solving your problem. It helps future readers. If the answers weren't helpful leave comments below them. So the poster can update them accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using an RTF file. If you use atext file instead it would yield 3 lines as expected. However you can further improve the code like so.

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\data\\sample.rtf"))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

You can try the [RTFEditorKit](http://java-sl.com/advanced_rtf_editor_kit.html). It supports images and text as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading a RTF Document. If you want to read the text only you can try reading it into a byte array and parsing out the text using swings rtfeditorkit.

```
Path path = Paths.get("path/to/file");
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);

RTFEditorKit rtfParser = new RTFEditorKit();
Document document = rtfParser.createDefaultDocument();
rtfParser.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(data), document, 0);
String text = document.getText(0, document.getLength());
```

[(Source)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26566102/2408342)